# Using epsilon and delta show the continuity of a function with two variables at the point (0, 0)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

The function is this :
$f(x,y)=(x^3-y^2)\sin(x)$

I came to this :
$ 0 < \sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2} < \delta$ and $|(x^3-y^2)\sin(x)|$

But not sure where to go further..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to understand the problem you were asked to solve. What (in your understanding) is the definition of continuity at the point $(0,0)$?

Comment: Well, speaking very simply, it shows that a limit exists at point (0, 0), and the function is basically not 'broken' and therefore continuous. Please correct me if I misunderstood this.

Comment: Can you be more precise?  In terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: That is an intuitive description, but you seem to need a rigorous proof, which requires a justification of an exact definition. Can you give a *precise* definition of continuity at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Please consult your notes/textbook, if applicable, and then edit your question to include the precise $\epsilon, \delta$ constraint that needs to be satisfied.  The problem can not be attacked without it.  D_S's answer does give a somewhat alternative approach, but I still recommend starting with the necessary formal definition.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by precise ϵ,δ? There are none given in my textbook, I just have to prove it's continuous at the point. I'm feeling ignorant right now for not knowing what do you want from me, but I'm always open if you could explain where I'm wrong.

Comment: You may want to read some proofs of other continuity results (e.g. show that $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous at $3$) and understand what an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof is.  Right now it looks like you're unequipped to begin this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that $x^3-y^2$ and $\sin x$ are each continuous at $(0,0)$?  Do you know how the proof goes that the product of two continuous functions is continuous?  You can combine these arguments and essentially redo that proof to produce a direct $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the continuity of $(x^3-y^2)\sin x$ at $(0,0)$.